# If a string word contains particular characters and remove the word that contains the characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Suppose I have a data as follows,

```
data['sentences']

This is a sentence
Donald Trump
Machine Learning
Python is good
```

I want to search for pattern of characters and if we find one, need to remove that word which contains the characters.

Suppose I want to remove words with "enc" , "ood" and "ump", the output should be,

```
data['sentences']

This is a 
Donald 
Machine Learning
Python is
```

I tried the following where I used re.sub,

```
re.sub("enc", "", y)
```

But this is giving output like, `This is a sente` . I am not sure how to remove the entire word.

Can anybody help me in doing this is python? I want to find the efficient way to do this because, I want to run this for nearly 1 Billion records using pyspark. Can anybody help me in doing this?

Thanks

Comment: This is not a jobs board. We are not here to "help" you. You post your code, you explain what it should do, you explain how it ISN'T doing that, and we'll (maybe) try help fix it.

Comment: I dont understand, your data is a dictionary, a file, a list..? what is `data['sentences']`?

Comment: @MarcB sorry. I did try few things. Just didn't mention it here. I can add it now.

Comment: @RafaelCardoso It is a dataframe and one of the column of dataframe is sentences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add iterations before and after the identifier:

```
re.sub(r'\w*enc\w*', '', y)
```

That would replace with blank all the alphanumeric characters along with the specified string (i.e. the word it is contains within).